# Page stalls when a asynchronous request is processing in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have two UpdatePanel in a single asp.net page.One has a submit button and a progress bar , on click on this button there is a process which fetch the data from a XML file and stores in Database.

Second update panel is used to display the content from a log about the progress of the data insertion from XML and it is updated using a timer control.

Now the problem is that when a request is submitted from first panel , second panel stop updating the content.

Should I try any other library or some sort of jq metohods to update page.

thanx in advance

here is my code,...

```
 <asp:scriptmanager runat="server" ID="scrpManager">     </asp:scriptmanager> 
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updLeft" runat ="server">
 <ContentTemplate>   
    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" onclick="Submit_Click" 
        Text="Process" />
        </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers >
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="Button3" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>  
      <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updLeft" 
        ID="UpdateProgress21">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="loadingbox">
            <img src="spinner.gif" align="absmiddle" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="lblProgress21" runat="server">Please wait while processing...</asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlRight" runat ="server" >
<ContentTemplate >  
 <asp:Timer Interval="1000" ID="timer1" runat="server" ontick="timer1_Tick"  ></asp:Timer> 

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeader ="false" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" runat="server">
    <Columns >
    <asp:BoundField  DataField ="status_MSG" HeaderText ="" /> 
    </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers >
   <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="timer1" EventName="Tick" />

  </Triggers> 
    </ajax:UpdatePanel> 

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do insertion process , takes 30 minutes,
}
```

Comment: You need to post some code - what are `UpdateMode` for your updates panels? Is it set to conditional that would explain the issue.

Comment: added my code..have tried both of the update modes

Answer (score 0):

I've had nothing but misery with update panels. I urge you to use an alternative such as client side templates. Knockout.js and Angular.js are probably good places to start.

If you paste your code, or a (non) working example of your issue, I'll try offer a fix.

Comment: The code seems incomplete. I don't see the end of updPnlRight.